# vuejs multiple themes with scoped css in single file vue components

Tags: css, webpack, sass, vue.js, vuejs2

So let's assume we have a variables scss file like the following

```
$darken-percentage: 15%;

$primary-color: #2aaae1;
$dim-primary-color: darken($primary-color, $darken-percentage);

$complementary-color: #faaf48;
$dim-complementary-color: darken($complementary-color, $darken-percentage);

$background-color: #1d1f29;

$middleground-color: #313444;
$dim-middleground-color: darken($middleground-color, $darken-percentage);
$light-middleground-color: lighten($middleground-color, $darken-percentage);
```

In the main.js we could use `@import 'variables.scss'`
what if I have two themes and I want to change on user action I could have 2 variables files and conditionally import either based on user actions but what about single file vue components 
like

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
  @import '../../theme/_variables.scss';
  .bm-upload{
    background: $primary-color;
  }
</style>
```

Then the import will not work so is there anyway for me to have global variables files and use it in other files without re importing it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to import both style files and change a parent element's class. The browser will immediately apply the styles when the class changes.

You can, for example, change the body's class with [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and have all styles depend on that.

```
created(){
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.add("theme1");
},
methods: {
    changeTheme(){
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.classList.remove("theme1");
        body.classList.add("theme2");
    }
}
```

Style should inherit from the theme class name, like this:

```
.theme1 {
    .exampleClass {
       padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: While Dom manipulation is generally not required with Vue, in this case Body is outside of the Vue instance and its just fine to use the browser's classList

Comment: but then i won't be able to use scoped styling which is the whole issue is about anyways

Comment: Scoped styling will not work with this use case. Why do you need scoped styling? Are you worried about conflicts with other components?

Comment: but even if i don't have scoped styles at least i want to have my component style in the same file as my component how can i achieve that

Comment: Just put the styles on the component file. If the styles are not scoped, they apply everywhere.